# How to get the final features?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, data-analysis

The original data is `Y`, the size of `Y` is `L*n` ( `n` is the number of features; `L` is the number of observations.  `B` is the covariance matrix of the original data `Y`. Suppose `A` is the eigenvectors of the covariance matrix `B`. I represent `A` as `A = (e1, e2,...,en)`, where `ei` is an eigenvector. Matrix `Aq` is the first `q` eigenvectors and `ai` be the row vectors of `Aq`: `Aq = (e1,e2,...,eq) = (a1,a2,...,an)'`. I want to apply the k-means algorithm to `Aq` to cluster the row vector `ai` to `k` clusters or more (note: I do not want to apply k-means algorithm to the eigenvector `ei` to `k` clusters). For each cluster, only the vector closest to the center of cluster is retained, and the feature corresponding to this vector is finally selected as the informative features.

My question is:

1) What is the difference between applying the k-means algorithm to `Aq` to cluster the row vector `ai` to `k` clusters and applying k-means algorithm to `Aq` to cluster the eigenvector `ei` to `k` clusters?

2) the `closest_vectors` I get is from this command: `closest_vectors = Aq(min_idxs, :)`, the size of the `closest_vectors` is `k*q`double. How to get the final informative features? Since the final informative features have to be obtained from the original data `Y`.

Thanks!

I found two function about pca and pfa:

```
function [e m lambda, sqsigma] = cvPca(X, M)

[D, N] = size(X);

if ~exist('M', 'var') || isempty(M) || M == 0
    M = D; 
end
M = min(M,min(D,N-1));

%% mean subtraction
m = mean(X, 2);  %%% calculate the mean of every row

X = X - repmat(m, 1, N);

%% singular value decomposition. X = U*S*V.' or X.' = V*S*U.'
[U S V] = svd(X,'econ');

e = U(:,1:M);

if nargout > 2
    s = diag(S);

    s = s(1:min(D,N-1));

    lambda = s.^2 / N; % biased (1/N) estimator of variance

end

% sqsigma. Used to model distribution of errors by univariate Gaussian
if nargout > 3
    d = cvPcaDist(X, e, m); % Use of validation set would be better

    N = size(d,2);

    sqsigma = sum(d) / N; % or (N-1) unbiased est

end
end
```

%/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
function [IDX, Me] = cvPfa(X, p, q)
[D, N] = size(X);
if ~exist('p', 'var') || isempty(p) || p == 0
    p = D;
end
p = min(p, min(D, N-1));
if ~exist('q', 'var') || isempty(q)
    q = p - 1;
end

%% PCA step
[U Me, Lambda] = cvPca(X, q);

%% cluter row vectors (q x D). not col
[Cl, Mu] = kmeans(U, p, 'emptyaction', 'singleton', 'distance', 'sqEuclidean');

%% find axis which are nearest to mean vector
IDX = logical(zeros(D,1));
for i = 1:p
    Cli = find(Cl == i);
    d = cvEucdist(Mu(i,:).', U(Cli,:).');
    [mini, argmin] = min(d);
    IDX(Cli(argmin)) = 1;
end
```

Comment: I've rolled back your changes because by removing a good majority of your question, our answers no longer make any sense.

Comment: On a minor note, I suspect it was you who gave me a whole slew of upvotes on various answers that I authored yesterday.  Though your intentions are noble and I'm flattered, those actually harm me in the long run.  This is what is known [as serial upvoting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me) and it can be interpreted as voting fraud.  The system doesn't know whether it's a user with a different account trying to upvote his/her own posts, or if it's someone legitimate.  If you do want to vote for my posts, do it gradually over time :)

Comment: No not at all.  I'm someone who likes answering questions and I have a high enough reputation to be a trusted user.  However, editing your posts without approval was given to me at 2K reputation, and it isn't part of what you get as a trusted user, which requires >20K reputation.  As a trusted user, that allows me to have some privileges when it comes to operating here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user

Comment: No problem :) Actually, if you want quicker help, come see me in the MATLAB chat room.  That's where I hang out often! http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/matlab-and-octave

Comment: @rayryeng, can you answer this question: as Olologin said  "But clustering rows of PCA result can provide something useful." My question is: How to applying the k-means algorithm to Aq to cluster the row vector ai to k clusters? How to represent it by using Matlab?

Comment: What you are doing is reducing the amount of features that each sample takes to a reduced set.  By doing this, you may avoid the curse of dimensionality and perhaps overfitting where features that are really not required for classification and/or learning are eliminated and avoided for use.

Comment: @rayryeng, can you represent it by using Matlab? I mean just to realize " applying the k-means algorithm to Aq to cluster the row vector ai to k clusters" in Matlab?

Comment: Just apply `kmeans` on `Aq` instead of `A`.  Make sure that each row is a sample and each column is a feature.  What you wanted before was to cluster on the **transpose** of `Aq`... that is, clustering each column of `Aq` and that doesn't work.

Comment: @rayryeng, you just said apply kmeans to Aq', not to Aq. the size of Aq is n*q.

Comment: @rayryeng, you said "What you wanted before was to cluster on the transpose of Aq... that is, clustering each column of Aq and that doesn't work."

Comment: @rayryeng, the column of Aq are eigenvectors. Aq comes from A, the column of A are eigenvectors. the answer said "not cluster the eigenvectors" . did I misunderstand something?

Comment: @rayryeng, are you still there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing Olologin's comments, it doesn't make sense to cluster the eigenvectors of the covariance matrix, or the columns of the `U` matrix of the SVD.  Eigenvectors in this case are all orthogonal so if you tried to cluster them, you would only get one member per cluster and this cluster's centroid is defined by the eigenvector itself.

Now, what you're really after is selecting out the features in your data matrix that describe your data in terms of discriminatory analysis.

The functions that you have provided both compute the SVD and pluck out the `k` principal components of your data and also determine which features out of these `k` to select as the most prominent.  By default, the amount of features to select out is equal to `k`, but you can override this if you want.  Let's just stick with the default.

The `cvPfa` function performs this feature selection for you, but a warning to you that the data matrix in the function is organized where each **row is a feature** and each **column is a sample**.  The output is a `logical` vector that tells you which features are the strongest to select in your data.

Simply put, you just do this:

```
k = 10; %// Example
IDX = cvPfa(Y.', k);
Ynew = Y(:,IDX);
```

This code will choose the 10 most prominent features in your data matrix and pluck out those 10 features that are the most representative of your data, or the most discriminative.  You can then use the output for whatever application you're targetting.

Answer (score 1):

1) I don't think that clustering eigenvectors (columns of PCA result) of covariance matrix makes any sense. All eigenvectors pairwise orthogonal and equally far one from another in sense of Euclidian distance. You can pick any eigenvectors and compute distance between them, distance will be sqrt(2) between any pair. But clustering rows of PCA result can provide something useful.

Comment: here I use cosine distance, not Euclidian distance.

Comment: @Shawn, in that case you will get always 0, because all eigenvectors orthogonal to each other (angle between them is 90 degrees or pi/2) and their norm is always 1. cos(pi/2)=0

Comment: @Shawn, i mean only case with eigenvectors of covariance matrix. In general case with any other vectors this distance should work.

Comment: @Shawn - You can't use cosine distance on eigenvectors.  You will get 0.

Comment: @Olologin, you said "But clustering rows of PCA result can provide something useful."   How to applying the k-means algorithm to Aq to cluster the row vector ai to k clusters? How to represent it by using Matlab?

Comment: @Shawn, you already clustering rows in cvPfa function when calling kmeans function.